How to specify parse mode in Telegram (TMA) native share popup?
Using the telegram bot API, one can specify the parse_mode to HTML or Markdown/MarkdownV2. In a telegram mini-app, the native "Share" popup screen (with Chat select) can be opened as follows:
window.Telegram.WebApp.openTelegramLink(
    `https://t.me/share/msg_url?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`
)

Where url is the URL to be shared and text is the description text accompanying it. When giving text as **Test** or *Test* or <b>Test</b>, it just gets sent/shown with the raw * and <b> tags/chars instead of formatting it as expected (Test).
How can one specify the formatting in this native TMA share popup screen?
